# Difference between AOP & inheritance in OOPS concept?

Tags: oop, terminology, aop

Can u please clarify my doubt regarding the concept behind AOP & INHERITANCE concept in 
OOP ?
We can use the same services through inheritance also .Then why we will go for AOP in spring  framework?

Answer (score 0):

Aspects are for intercepting calls and injecting logic. For instance, you may have an existing service class and you may want to log all incoming calls to that class -- then you would "simply" use AOP to intercept the incoming calls and perform logging in the interceptor.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Inheritance is just when you create a class that is more specific than an existing class. You may have a BusinessService and inherit a ScalableBusinessService from that, or a B2BIntegrationBusinessService... The inheriting class thus inherits methods and properties from the parent, and adds its own methods or overrides existing (virtual) methods. This is a totally different thing than injecting logic with AOP.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: user1228416 has asked for the difference but you just specified the AOP and didn't said anything about INHERITANCE.